# intergrating a typescript module in my existing angular 1.5 enterprise project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular2-template

Can i intergrate a typescript module in my existing angular 1.5 enterprise project. The main problem is : Can i invoke a ts file from a js file.
Its not a typescipt framework or API.
Controller to Component call.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from js to ts is relatively painless as you can write normal js code inside a ts file.  Checkout the angular migration guide https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#migrating-to-typescript